# Display every combination of a given array in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program with my teacher that displays every possible combination of n numbers (for example, if n = 2, it displays from 01,02,03 etc.. to 89.) I'm using multiple tabs, incrementing the last one to go up to 9, and then incrementing the one just before so I can go from 09 to 12, and so on, but I don't really know how to proceed.

I'm quite new to C programming, so feel free to tell me if anything can be made better.

```
#include <unistd.h>

ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

ft_affichage(int tab[], int nb)
{
    int index = 0;
    
    while(index < nb)
    {
        ft_putchar(tab[index] + 48);
        ft_putchar(',');
        ft_putchar(' ');
        index++;
    }
}

int ft_end(int tab[], int nb)
{
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < nb ; index++)
    {
        if (tab[index] != 9 - nb + 1 + index)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
void ft_print_comb_n(int nb)
{
    int comb[nb];
    int index = 0;
    
    // init comb
    while(index < nb)
    {
        comb[index] = index;
        index++;
    }
    ft_affichage(comb, nb);
    while(ft_end(comb, nb) == 0)
    {
        // incrementer comb;
        int i = nb - 1;
        int max = 9;
        
        while(comb[0] != 9 - nb + 1 + index && comb[nb- 1] != 9 )
        {
            comb[nb - 1]++;
        }
    {
        
    }
        }
        
    //afficher comb;
      ft_affichage(comb, nb);
    }


int main(void)
{
    ft_print_comb_n(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your exact problem?

Comment: when using debug mode,  i saw that comb[1] didnt stopped at 9 when using || instead of &&, my objective is now to increment comb[0] to continue the listing

Comment: Please state the problem in the question itself. It will be easier for others. And I don't even understand the question. It says "displays every possible combination of n numbers". If that's true, every single 2 digit number should appear but that's not true seeing the example.

Comment: So, for example, `22` and `41` are not possible 2-digit combinations? You only want combinations where digits are strictly increasing, right?

Comment: yes exactly, sorry if my question isnt clear, i didn't knew how to explain this very well

Answer (score 0):

> so feel free to tell me if anything can be made better

Depending on the requirements your teacher gave, the solution below is possible and very simple. It makes use of printf feature that allow to print a variable number of digit of an integer number with leading zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void ft_print_comb_n(int nb)
{
    // Compute the limit based on the number of digits
    int maxN = (int)(pow(10, nb) + 0.5);

    for (int i = 0; i < maxN; i++)
        printf("%0*d\n", nb, i);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ft_print_comb_n(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is based on some old code of mine, but I've forgotten how it works.

```
int ft_debut(int tab[], int n, int k)
{
    if (k <= 0 || k > n)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    while (k--)
    {
        tab[k] = k;
    }
    return 1;
}

int ft_suivant(int tab[], int n, int k)
{
    int i = k;
    if (k < 0 || k > n)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    while (i--)
    {
        int x = tab[i];
        if (x < --n)
        {
            do
            {
                tab[i++] = ++x;
            }
            while (i < k);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void ft_print_comb_n(int nb)
{
    int comb[nb];
    int va;
    
    for (va = ft_debut(comb, 10, nb); va; va = ft_suivant(comb, 10, nb))
    {
        ft_affichage(comb, nb);
    }
}
```

`ft_debut` fills `tab[]` with the initial combination (`tab[i] = i` for `i` from 0 to `k`) if the `n` and `k` parameters are valid.

`ft_suivant` "increments" the combination in `tab[]` if the `n` and `k` values are valid and the combination in `tab[]` has not yet reached the maximum value. `i` scans backwards from `k-1` to 0, stopping when a `tab[i]` that can be incremented (the maximum allowed value for `tab[i]` is `n-k+i`) has been reached or when `tab[0]` is already at its maximum allowed value (so `tab[]` already contains the final combination). If a suitable `tab[i]` is found, it is incremented by 1, and any remaining elements from `tab[i+1] up to` tab[k-1]` are set to one more than their preceding element.

Example of `ft_suivant` for `n=10`, `k=2`, `tab[0]=2`, `tab[1]=9`:

- `int i = k;` — i=2
- `while (i--)` — true, i=1
- `{`
- `int x = tab[i];` — x=9 (tab[1])
- `if (x < --n)` — n=9, false
- `}`
- `while (i--)` — true, i=0
- `{`
- `int x = tab[i];` — x=2 (tab[0])
- `if (x < --n)` — n=8, true
- `{`
- `do`
- `{`
- `tab[i++] = ++x;` — x=3, tab[0]=3, i=1
- `}`
- `while (i < k);` — true
- `do`
- `{`
- `tab[i++] = ++x;` — x=4, tab[1]=4, i=2
- `}`
- `while (i < k);` — false
- `return 1;`

The combination has been successfully "incremented" from {2, 9} to {3, 4}.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! i have a question on your code still, i dont fully understand what i and k are for

Comment: `k` is effectively what you called `nb`. The names `n` and `k` where chosen to match the mathematical phrase "n choose k". `i` is just an index for accessing the elements of `tab[]`. I have edited the description of what `ft_suivant` is effectively doing to increment the combination.